# What representation of chat text data should I use for user classification?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, naivebayes

I'm trying to train a classifier to classify text from a chat between 2 users so later on I can predict who of the two users is more likely to say X sentence/word. To get there I mined the text from the chat log and ended up with two arrays of words, `UserA_words` and `UserB_words`.

In which format do I have to transform this arrays to pass it to a classifier like naiveBayes or SVM? How do I pass e.g. a bag of words representation to a classifier?

Comment: Asking what ML representation to use for a specific classification task is on-topic at sister site [DataScience.SE](http://datascience.stackexchange.com). Please migrate there.

Comment: Putting this on hold is not constructive: either migrate to DataScience.SE or leave open here. My answer shows that this has an actual answer.

Comment: @smci Sorry, i'm new here, I posted a similar question in Data Science SE, but how do I migrate this one ? Thank you in advance

Comment: whiteTea you can't do anything - it's the users with [>3k reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) who voted to close instead of migrate, and are not voting to reopen or migrate.

Comment: Please don't crosspost, but since you already posted [this](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/14730/chat-text-classification-aproach/14768) at DataScience.SE let's take things over there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking what ML representation you should use for user-classification of chat text.

bag-of-words and word-vector are the main representations generally used in text-processing. However user-classification of chat is not the usual text-processing task, we look for telltale features indicative of a specific user.
Here are some:

- character length, word length, sentence length of each comment
- typing speed (esp. if you have timestamps in seconds)
- ratio of punctuation (e.g. 17 punctuation symbols in 80 chars = 17/80)
- ratio of capitalization
- ratio of numerals
- ratio of whitespace
- character n-grams (and notice these can pick up e.g. *l0ser, f##k, :-)* )
- use of Unicode (emojis, symbols e.g. stars)
- ratio of specific punctuation (e.g. how many '.', '!', '?', '*', '#' )
- word-counts, esp. anything statistically anomalous
- anything else you can think of that seems predictive for these two users, e.g. number of misspelled words per sentence (may be actual typos, or come from predictive swiping on a cellphone)